# Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '44058'

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

**Hola** Estoy ingresando datos desde un archivo `excel`a mi base de datos desde laravel, el problema que me encuentro es que al momento de `importar` la informacion en el campo que tengo en mysql como `timestamp` me da error, estoy trabajando con la libreria de `laravel excel 3.1`.

Adjunto codigo del controlador (import):

```
 return new tbl_calibracion([

        'cal_certificado'=>$row[18],
        'cal_solicitadoPor'=>$row[19],
        'cal_informeRechazo'=>$row[20],
        'cal_soliLabvantage'=>$row[21],
        'cal_informeResultado'=>$row[22],
        'cal_calibrador'=>$row[23],
        'cal_registradoPor'=>$row[24],
        'cal_fechaCalibracion'=>$row[25],
        'cal_fechaRecepcion'=>$row[26],
        'cal_proximaCalibracion'=>$row[27],
  ]);
```

Adicionalmente adjunto el codigo de mi controlador principal:

```
 public function importExcel(Request $request) 
{

  $this->validate($request, [
  'import_file'  => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx'
  ]);



  Excel::import(new CalibracionImport,$request->import_file);

  return back()->with('success', 'Datos Excel Importados Satisfactoriamente.');
}
```

Estuve probando con el siguiente codigo

```
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[25])
```

Pero al momento de hacer el `insert` los datos que estaban arriba los elimina y les cambia las fechas así:

```
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1970-01-01 00:00:00,
```

Comment: Hola Rafael. Esa fecha que pone Laravel es la fecha nula (vamos, cuando no hay fecha). Has comprobado que para esa fila hay valor en esa celda? Por lo demás, no veo nada raro, el uso de la función excelToDateTimeObject es correcto

Comment: Me fije que al poner esos campos manualmente osea con comillas simples y el formato en fecha tambien me pasaba el mismo error, me quitaba los datos anteriores

Answer (score 0):

La función `excelToDateTimeObject` requiere un entero o un flotante según la documentación:

https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.3.1/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Shared/Date.html

Te recomiendo utilizar Carbon para transformar las fechas, sería algo asi:

```
return new tbl_calibracion([

        'cal_certificado'=>$row[18],
        'cal_solicitadoPor'=>$row[19],
        'cal_informeRechazo'=>$row[20],
        'cal_soliLabvantage'=>$row[21],
        'cal_informeResultado'=>$row[22],
        'cal_calibrador'=>$row[23],
        'cal_registradoPor'=>$row[24],
        'cal_fechaCalibracion'=>Carbon\Carbon::parse($row[25]),
        'cal_fechaRecepcion'=>Carbon\Carbon::parse($row[26]),
        'cal_proximaCalibracion'=>$row[27],
  ]);
```

Asumiendo que `cal_fechaRecepcion` tambien es un timestamp en la base de datos.

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Cuando utilizo ese codigo las fechas me salen así = `1970-01-01 12:08:12` pero la fecha del excel es 14/08/2019

Comment: Puedes forzar el formato de fecha de entrada: `Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $row[25]);` así te debería de funcionar, si no te funciona, vigila que las fechas no tengan espacios y el importador te las esté leyendo bien

Comment: La fecha necesito que este en el formato que me sale, solo que necesito que me recoja la fecha que es, mi fecha es 2019-08-14 y no se porque me sale esa

Comment: Cuando utilizo tu codigo me sale lo siguiente `The separation symbol could not be found
 Data missing`

Comment: La fecha del excel es 2019-08-14? el formato de salida, lo puedes formatear con carbon también, pero primero tienes que convertir la cadena en fecha, si la separación es con guiones, debes utilizar el formato `"Y-m-d"` segun la fecha que me has mostrado en el anterior mensaje, de todas formas, intenta igualar el formato segun el que aparezca en el excel, siendo Y el año representado en 4 numeros: 2019, m el mes en 2 numeros y d el dia en dos numeros. lo que pongas entre estos caracteres debe ser la separacion de las fechas

Comment: En excel me pone la fecha así 15/08/2019 pero la estoy metiendo en un timestamp que quede 2019-08-15, segun eso entonces pondria así? `Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('yyyy-mm-dd', $row[25]);`

Comment: @RafaelMonroyRodriguez , con carbon puedes parsear la fecha segun el formato de entrada, y sacar una fecha segun el formato de salida, en tu caso sería asi: `Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $row[25])->format('Y-m-d');` Prueba si así te funciona definitivamente ;)